# XAML 2009 and .NET 4.6/Windows 10

Tags: xaml, windows-10, .net-4.6, xaml-2009

WPF never ended up supporting [XAML 2009](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee792007(v=vs.110).aspx), which is a shame because it added some useful extensions, such as generic type parameters and complex `x:Key` values.

UWP seems to have built upon WPF. Does it, or anything else in .NET 4.6/Windows 10 support XAML 2009, six years after the fact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The situation in 2018:

For **UWP**, the answer is no. [It's built over XAML 2006](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/xaml-namespaces-and-namespace-mapping).

For **WPF**, the answer is mainly no. You can in theory use it but with [big caveats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/xaml-services/xaml-2009-language-features).

For **anything else**, the answer is yes: [Xamarin.Forms is XAML 2009 based.](https://blog.xamarin.com/introduction-to-xaml/)

The big question mark is [XAML Standard](https://github.com/Microsoft/xaml-standard). We haven't heard from it for a while and I think it was presumed that it's going to be XAML 2006 based because WPF and UWP are. You might find the following (open) GitHub issue interesting: [Use XAML 2009 as the basis for XAML Standard](https://github.com/Microsoft/xaml-standard/issues/45)